# Big game hunting on the continent

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I once went on a hunting expedition for five years across Europe, searching for a wonderful trophy for my lodge. It was a wonderful experience. I started in Poland and moved to France, then went to England to meet with my 3 friends, Lee, Stuart and I forget the name of the last one. (He's a light little devil. You could throw him around without breaking a sweat) My favorite thing I found was a huge mass of fireflies, though I did manage to catch a glimpse of a tortoise. My greatest achievement was hunting three different big cats. The only issue is I have misplaced my trophies now, and I can't remember what they were. **Can you tell me what they were?**

Comment: Could someone suggest better tags? I really don't know what this would be under.

Comment: why...you little...hunting for fun. that's cruel. :)

Comment: You may use [tag:geography] if that's relevant to the puzzle.

Comment: If there's no answers soon, I'll add a tag that should be a big clue.

Comment: I honestly don't know why I was thinking of Pokémon but hey

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are referring to ...

> .. [World War II tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanks_in_World_War_II).
> The five year period probably refers to USA entering the war after the [attack on Pearl Harbor in 1941](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Pearl_Harbor).
> Your friends were the [M3 Stuart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3_Stuart), [M3 Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3_Lee) and maybe the [M22 Locust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M22_Locust). You saw the [Sherman Firefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman_Firefly) and the [Tortoise heavy assault tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortoise_heavy_assault_tank). The 3 cats were probably the [Panther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panther_tank), [Tiger I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_I) and [Tiger II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_II) (aka. King Tiger). There was also the [Panzer VII Löwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzer_VII_L%C3%B6we) (Lion) but according to Wikipedia it only existed on paper.