# Someone graffiti'd my task list!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, history, odd-one-out

I need to perform some maintenance on my house, so the first thing I usually do is write a list of things I need to fix and what is wrong with them. I had it all written down so I went for a quick nap before I started work. The problem is someone has added a task to the list. I can't start work until I know which one is wrong. They must have inserted it cleverly into the list as I can't figure out which one it is. This is my list in its current state:

- Windows (distortion problem)
- Rats! (huge ones, everywhere!)
- Comet (might land nearby)
- Back garden water tank (Russian)
- Oboe (sounds weird)
- Tags (can't read what they say)

**Please tell me which one is wrong so I can begin work. I really don't like the sound of comets landing nearby.**

Hint 1

> Eveything on this list is written in English. Not all of it was originally in English however.

Comment: It must be Tags, because odd-one-out is one of the tags.

Comment: Lovely piece of lateral thinking there. Unfortunately isn't the answer.

Answer (score 5):

My first thought was this would be related to ...

> ... computers/programming, but after the [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32533/big-game-hunting-on-the-continent) and a bit of searching this seems again to be related to WW II.
>
>  **Windows (distortion problem):** [Radar countermeasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_%28codename%29) from WW II.
>  **Rats! (everywhere!):** The SOE developed [rat bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_rat) during WW II ([alternative link with images](http://www.military-history.org/weapons-technology/back-to-the-drawing-board-exploding-rats.htm)). This might also refer to the [ram air turbine (RAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_air_turbine) which should be present on most aircraft.
>  **Comet (might land nearby):** <s>A [British tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28tank%29) from WW II.</s> This could be the [Messerschmitt Me 163 Komet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_163).
>  **Back garden water tank (Russian):** Not quite sure about this one. It might refer to a Soviet amphibious tank from WW II. Wikipedia lists 3 of them ([T-37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-37_tank), [T-38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-38_tank) and [T-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-40)). This might also refer to a Russian tank [recovered from an Estonian lake](http://englishrussia.com/2006/09/17/russian-tank-recovered-from-the-lake-after-50-years-been-there/), which was captured by the Germans and had German markings.
>  **Oboe (sounds wierd):** A [British targeting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oboe_%28navigation%29) from WW II.
>  **Tags (can't read what they say):** <s>[Transparent Armor Gun Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Armor_Gun_Shield), which as far as I can tell was not used during WW II and is therefore the wrong item.</s> This might refer to the [Telegraphist Air Gunners](http://www.fleetairarm.com/exhibition/telegraphist-air-gunners/5-11.aspx).
>
>  Not sure about the wrong item yet, but 5 items may be aircraft related.

Comment: A good attempt, though not all for the identified items are quite right. The problems with each thing are a clue as to what they are.

Comment: @Universalerror I changed one item, can you at least tell how many of them are correct?

Comment: You've got all but two of them correct. You may have to broaden what you are looking for with one of them.

Comment: @Universalerror Am I getting closer?

Comment: You're on the right track with the one you're changing, though it still isn't right. I've edited the question a little as I realise it wasn't as clear as i'd've liked it to be. You're also correct in editing tags. Reread the clues for the items.

Comment: Looking at all the links I think the answer might be `Oboe` as it is the only thing not involving Germans per say.. But I can't be so sure and also because that depends on the meaning of `rats!`